# Counting Lines of file having row delimiters in unix sll script

Tags: awk

DataFile content

```
1234t56
78t7891
```

here delimiter is `t`

and i need output as

```
3
```

(the three objects I want counted would be `1234`, `56<newline>78` and `7891`)

it worked with grep i.e. counting occurrence of delimiter and then add one will give no. of lines

but its performance hindrance anything in awk could help

Answer (score 4):

Another awk way for your updated question

```
awk -vRS='t' 'END{print NR}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
echo "1234t5678t7891" | awk -F't' '{print NF}'
```

If processing file contents, u can change it to:

```
awk -F't' '{print NF}' File
```

Here, we set the delimiter as `'t' (-F't')`. Then we print the number of fields `(print NF)`

For your edited question:

```
tr -d '\n' < File | awk -F't' '{print NF}'
```

Comment: That might have a hard time bringing in a large file (treated as a single line) into columns.

Comment: u can try and c if there's any performance issue... unfortunately, i cannot foretell the behaviour.. lets c if someone else can give better inputs..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `t` is your *line* delimiter as seems to be the case by your phrase "counting occurrence of delimiter and then add one will give no. of lines", one way is to simply delete all characters that *aren't* the delimiter and count the remaining ones:

```
pax> ((count = $(echo '1234t5678t7891' | tr -c -d 't' | wc -c)))
pax> ((count++))
pax> echo $count
3
```

This takes about 24 seconds wall time for a 3.5G file I just happened to have lying around, but only about 6 seconds CPU time:

```
pax> ll qq2
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax good_lookers 3541710600 Dec 30 16:32 qq2

pax> time ((count = $(tr -c -d 't' <qq2 | wc -c)))
real    0m24.163s
user    0m4.436s
sys     0m2.060s

pax> ((count++)) ; echo $count
10844976
```

Whether that's fast enough, I couldn't say, since you haven't provided the requirements there. Short of writing a bespoke program utilising things like large buffers, I don't think you'll get much better performance than a pipeline like that.

But, in any case, you should benchmark any potential solution with your own data as well. The primary mantra of optimisation is: *measure, don't guess!*

Comment: Thanks for solution , but my data file is in gigs

Comment: @Nishad, I've provided some sample timing for a file in the G-range but you should test it against your own data.

Comment: Just did some tests and this is by far the quickest solution i can find, nice work +1.